# Exclude Latest Article From View?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I'm working with Views 3, and I'm trying to figure out how to best accomplish the following scenario:

On my front page, I'd like to have my articles set up as follows:

On the left, a large thumbnail is shown for the latest article. This accounts for the Title, Author, Post date, and a short summary with a comment count.

To the side, I have a block created in Views that would show the previous three articles with smaller thumbnails, author information, post date, summary, and comment counts.

What I need to know is this: How can I set up both Article views so that:

-The view on the left only shows the absolute latest article.

-The view on the right always excludes the latest article from the listing.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a view with two displays of type block. Arrange some region or panel method to display them in side by side fashion.

Create view, select its type as node, choose fields and filters according to your requirement.

**For View display having latest item:**

Click `Pager` from your view settings and define `Items per page` as 1 and set sort order Date created/posted as descending.

**For View display having next three items:**

Click `Pager` settings and define `Items per page` as 3 and set `Offset` as 1 and define the same date order as for the previous view display.

**Thumbnails settings:**

While selecting your fields particularly selecting image field (must be part of your post's content type) as thumbnail for post, choose image style. The image style are thumbnail sizes and formats. See the interface on `example.com/admin/config/media/image-styles` to add your custom image forma-tors so that a proper thumbnail can appear on each view display.

Comment: Thanks, guys! That was exactly what I needed to know, it works exactly the way I want it to! :)

Comment: @John if this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking the answer as 'accepted'. [How to accept answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 3):

In pager options set offset to 1.

Comment: Nice tweak. +1. Maybe the easiest.